# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) displayed on console

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, forms

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AxHs.png)
My file structure is that
index.html, script.js and login.js are all in the same folder, root folder. I am pretty new so I haven't really created any subfolders yet. The connection to the database happens successfully but the linking between the script.js and index.html doesn't work for some reason?
The console itself isn't being displayed and gives an error. Any help is much appreciated.

login.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database : "crud[enter image description here][1]db"
});
connection.connect(function(error){
    if (error) throw error
    else console.log("connected to the database succesfully")
});



app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
    // res.send('Hello')
});

app.listen(4500);
```

index.html

```
<style>
    :root{
        --lightblue: #a8dadc;
    }
    *{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    body{
        background-color: var(--lightblue);
    }
    h1{
      color: #F1FAEE;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 25px;
    }
    #login-page{
        background-color: #f5616d;
        width: 65vw;
        height: 50vh;
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #my-form{
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
        grid-gap: 15px;
    }
    #form-header{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 25px;
    }
</style>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> CRUD </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='script.js'></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <main id = "main">
      <header id = "title">
      <h1> CRUD App </h1>
      <div id = "login-page">
        <div class = "login-form">
            <h2 id="form-header"> Enter your Login Credentials </h2>
            <form id="my-form" method="GET" action="">
                <label for="user-email">Email</label> <input id="user-email" type="email" name="login-form-email" placeholder="Email">
                <label for="user-password">Password</label> <input id="user-password" type="password" name="login-form-password" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Login</button> 
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>  
</html>
```

script.js

```
const formid = document.getElementById("my-form");
const username = document.getElementById("user-email");
const userpass = document.getElementById("user-pass");
formid.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('hello');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re referencing your JavaScript at `/static/script.js` in your HTML, but you haven’t created a `/static` route in your Express server.

Add the [`express.static` directive](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) somewhere after you declare `app`, but before `app.listen()`:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname));
```

You should also note your HTML is syntactically invalid as you’ve presented it here - a `<style>` block (or any block, for that matter) cannot reside outside the outermost `<html>` parent node, and should be nested within the `<head>` of your document instead.

Comment: I removed the 'static/script.js' and changed it to just 'script.js'. Do I still need to add the line you mentioned? The console still isn't loading up for me.

Comment: Just because you changed its reference doesn’t mean it will be served at that URL - you still haven’t configured that. Why not just add the `static` middleware per my suggestion?

Comment: I have added the above line of code and I still get the same error.